# Netplan & samba-ad-dc

Tags: boot, 18.04, netplan

I'm running an active directory on Ubuntu 18.04. I previously had one on 16.04 and it ran fine; I'm just rebuilding it with the new version and streamlining some stuff. Anyway, it works, but not on boot where the internal DNS fails. It can't find Kerberos and won't run any logon services for domain users.

To get it running properly, I have to log in under a local user and `netplan apply`.  I don't have to make any changes, just to manually reapply what should be (and seemingly is) getting applied on boot. Then everything runs fine.  Now that I know that's the fix, I could keep doing that... it's not like I reboot the domain controllers that often... but it's really kind of annoying.

This should be running properly on boot so I can immediately login under a domain user, but I can't figure out why it's working this way or how to fix it beyond scrapping netplan entirely and just running the network through the old ifupdown system. Can somebody explain to me what to do?

Comment: By "internal" DNS, do you mean one that's internal to the AD realm controller itself, running on localhost? Or is it on a different host, in which case, where are you configuring the information about the DNS server's address?

Comment: See https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Samba_Internal_DNS_Back_End

Comment: That being said, its moot.  I scrapped it and rebuilt the domain using Ubuntu 16.04.  It works fine now.

Comment: So little info to find on Samba ADDC and Ubuntu 18.04. All tutorials point to Networkmanager.conf and /etc/network/interfaces, files that no longer exist in this ubuntu version. Did you ever made the switch to 18.04 or still running on 16.04 ?

Answer (score 0):

After ending in the same situation after upgrading our AD DC to Ubuntu 18.04, I stumbled over the question. During research for other problems, I stumbled upon this nice [guide to install Samba as AD DC on Ubuntu 18.04](https://blog.ricosharp.com/posts/2019/Samba-4-Active-Directory-Domain-Controller-on-Ubuntu-18-04-Server)

What he did to resolve the resolve.conf issue preventing to startup Samba as AD DC (the blocked port 53) is to disable systemd-resolve completely. I will test this approach for now. This are the relevant steps to achive it:

```
~]$ sudo systemctl stop systemd-resolved
~]$ sudo systemctl disable systemd-resolved
~]$ sudo unlink /etc/resolv.conf
~]$ sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 192.168.122.70
search ad.example.com
~]$ sudo reboot
```

I hope this helps somebody.